# Delete Records using password

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a web app in PHP using Bootstrap .... but I a very very new to both languages ...

I am showing record from my SQL database on the website using using the plugin Datatables.  In my First I have 2 buttons Edit and Delete... they work perfectly

I want to improve my delete function by adding a prompt where i should Type a password before deleting.

This is the script behind the button Delete

```
<a onclick="javascript:return confirm(&quot;Are you sure, you want to delete customer?&quot;);return false;" href="<?php echo site_url("cust/delete/'+oObj.aData[0]+'");?>
```

this is the Delete function in the Cust constructor

```
function delete($id)
{
    if($id >0 ){
        $this->cust_model->cust_delete($id);
        $this->session->set_flashdata("message", 'Customer deleted successfully');
        redirect('cust');
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: you do **NOT** put a "delete" function behind a simple "click here" link. A bot will **NOT** execute the javascript and simply follow the link. Boom, now your entire database is gone. http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The_Spider_of_Doom.aspx

Comment: A confirm box is boolean.   you can use a `prompt` control to allow user input.   That said, this is VERY insecure.  You should do all auth'ing on the server.

Comment: Thanks Marc B for your answer... I definitely understood your point... Can you lead me through a good method I should use ... As I said, I am a very very newbie